# accesskey not working when inside iframe, unless iframe is clicked

Tags: html, iframe, access-keys

Hello I have an  inside my index.
Inside that  I have To some_html.html

however, pressing alt +s doesn't redirect me to some_html.html, unless I click on the  first.
Why is this?
and is there a fix for this?
or a work around to automatically focus on the  without clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<input autofocus style="opacity:0;">` to the source document of the iframe where the line `<a href="some_html.html" accesskey="s">To some_html.html</a>` is present.

This is somewhat cheating. I'm not sure if there are other ways to do it, or if there is a proper way of doing this, but it works like charm.

The answer code given above will create an invisible inputbox that auto focuses its self.
To make sure it won't block anything clickable, you can hide it underneath something with `style="opacity:0; z-index:-100; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"`. (change left and top to where you want it to be so it won't interfere or make empty spaces to text following it).